# Assigning methods to events on user controls declared in an interface

Tags: c#, events, interface

In C#, I am building custom controls to be used in a custom application. I want each control to implement an event that will fire if an exception or error (an internal check failure) occurs inside the controls. I created an interface that declares the event. I create user controls that implement the interface. Here's my problem.

When I add one of my custom controls to a form, I want to loop through the controls on the form, detect all controls that are my custom controls and then assign an event handler to the event I declare in the interface. I cannot find a way to cast an object to the type of the interface.

Consider:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    event ControlExceptionOccured ControlExceptionOccuredEvent;
...
}

public partial class TextControl : UserControl, IMyInterface {
...
  public event ControlExceptionOccured ControlExceptionOccuredEvent;
...
}
```

and on my form I use one of these TextControls. I have this method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control Control in Controls)
  {
    if (Control.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).FullName) != null)
    {
       ((IMyInterface)Control).ControlExceptionOccuredEvent += ControlExceptionHandler;
    }
  }
}
```

This complies but will not execute. How can I add ControlExceptionHandler to the event chain?

My thanks to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "will not execute"? Any reason for not using `if (Control is IMyInterface)` instead of calling `GetType` etc?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand yuo're not able to subscribe to the event cause IF condition returns FALSE. Did yuo try to write something like this ? :

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls){
    if((ctrl as IMyInterface) != null) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the same as `if (ctrl is IMyInterface) {do stuff}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler way to do it:

```
if (control is IMyInterface)
    ((IMyInterface)control).ControlExceptionOccuredEvent += ControlExceptionHandler;
```

... But the way you're doing it should work too, so you'll have to provide more details about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
((IMyInterface)Control).ControlExceptionOccuredEvent += ControlExceptionHandler;
```

generates

> Unable to cast object of type '...Text.TextControl' to type 'IMyInterface'.

I do not understand why not.

As a side note, I replaced

```
if (Control.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).FullName) != null)
```

with

```
if (Control is IMyInterface)
```

and it does not work. The second example never returns true. I also tried

```
if ((Control as IMyInterface) != null)
```

and it also never returns true.